# VLC transcoding RTMP with 12 second delay

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, video-streaming, vlc, rtmp

I am using `VLC player` to receive a RTMP stream from `Unreal Media Server` and transcode it with `ogg/theora` for `html5` `video` element. Here is command line code 
I use:

```
vlc.exe -I dummy rtmp://XX.XX.XX.XX:5119/live/LRFront :network-caching=0 :sout=#transcode{vcodec=theo,vb=200,scale=1,deinterlace=0,acodec=none}:http{mux=ogg,dst=:8181/stream.ogg}
```

But this produces 10-12 second delay when viewing and even freezes quite often.
When played directly in flash player (rtmp stream) there is 50ms delay at most. So it has to be something with transcoding. 
Could anyone point me in the right direction?

My PC specs:

CPU: Core i7
RAM: 16 GB
GPU: Nvidia Gefore GTX660

Comment: got lucky in reducing the delay?

Comment: @itsaboutcode I have not. Since then I moved to GStreamer.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Just wondering if you could provide me sample code of GStreamer.